# Some guidance required in phase binning

Tags: python, numpy, phase

very new to python and coding in general so excuse all the mess and everything that goes with it.

My goal is to create a code for the Phase Dispersion Minimization technique, not to use existing ones, and to apply it to the data https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Practical-Time-Series-Analysis/blob/master/Data%20Files/monthly-sunspot-number-zurich-17.csv.

Currently my code is as follows

```
from astropy.time import Time
```

`def MYpdm(TIME,DATA,num_bins,PERIOD):`

```
TIME = pd.to_datetime(TIME,format="%Y-%m")
pd.DataFrame(Sunspots)

time_arr = TIME.to_numpy()

t = Time(time_arr)


phase = ((t.jd - t[0].jd)%period)/period
dec_phase = phase - np.floor(phase)

bin_width = 1.0/float(num_bins)   # calculate the width of the bins

values = np.zeros(num_bins)



bins = np.zeros(num_bins)
num_per_bin = np.zeros(num_bins)


for i in range(len(DATA)):
    n = int(phase[i] / bin_width) # calculate bin number for this value
    bins[n] += DATA[i]    # add value to bin SUM OF BINS!!!!
    num_per_bin[n] += 1
    values[n] = np.array(DATA[i])


Average_per_bin = bins/num_per_bin
binEdges = np.arange(num_bins) * bin_width


Mean = sum(DATA) / len(DATA)
Total_variance = sum((xi - Mean) ** 2 for xi in DATA) / (len(DATA)-1)


#Bin_variance = sum((xi - Average_per_bin) ** 2 for xi in bins) / (len(bins)-1)
Bin_variance = sum((xi - Average_per_bin) ** 2 for xi in bins) / (len(bins)-1)

print('Total Variance is % s' %Total_variance)
print()
print('Sum of bins % s' %(bins))
print()
print('Number of data points in bin % s' %(num_per_bin))
print()
print('Average per bin is % s' %(Average_per_bin))
print()
print('Bin variance is % s' %(Bin_variance))
print()
return (values)
```

The reason why I have so many prints is because I want to see what is going on in an orderly fashion. I am happy with everything other than I need the individual values within the bins. 
The sum of bins produces the sum in each bin correctly, but I need to be able to calculate the variance within each bin and require the individual values that comprise the sum. I tried doing this in `values`, but can't figure out how to get all the required values, it just returns one.
I have added my output, as you can see, the part returned is just a single value for each bin instead of all of the values. I tried changing the indentation, no avail.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Output
Total Variance is 1887.8131081642057

Sum of bins [71788.1 32836.2 39945.7]

Number of data points in bin [970. 927. 923.]

Average per bin is [74.00835052 35.42200647 43.27811484]

Bin variance is [3.90301197e+09 3.90858406e+09 3.90744923e+09]

array([ 50.3,  33.4, 159.6])

Comment: Phase binning is not my area of expertise.  However, I *do* have a lot of practical experience in debugging.  :-)  Why are all of your `print` statements at the end?  If you want to know where you dropped from a vector to a single value, then trace the origins of the variables.  Get some `print` statements into the data and control flow.  Also, cut this problem down to 3-5 elements, not 30, and people will be more likely to read it.

Comment: Good point, I will cut it down a bit and see if it looks better. However, I have sort of pinpointed the issues being in the values section of the for loop. The return value is a single value per array entry, but there should be multiple values. Sort of an array of arrays is required. I will try and clean it up a bit

Comment: Instead of just getting the number of data points in each bin, I would like to have the actual values of each of those numbers to calculate the real variance. The bin variance printed is incorrect

Comment: The prints are all at the end since this is all part of a function and so it will end up at the end.